# Detecting SslStream socket disconnection

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream, sslstream, disconnection

I am using SslStream on top of NetworkStream that wraps a Socket, how could i detect Socket disconnection at this situation.

In another words i want to detect if the remote client closed the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get an EOS when reading, or an IOException when writing.

Comment: but when i use EndRead Method i did not receive the messages correctly can you please take a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415021/asynchronous-sslstream-error

Comment: @user1666700 Sorry, I have no idea about .Net asynchronous sockets.

Comment: :( i hope i get answer for that as soon as possible

Comment: Sorry but is there any other method instead of attempting to write or read ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the poll method on the inner socket:

```
if (client.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
{
    read = 0;
    read = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    if (read > 0)
    {
        Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read));
    }
    else
        throw new Exception("Socket closed");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to zero `read` immediately before reassigning it.